# Moment object with just time information (no date)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way to construct a moment object with just hour and minute information?

I tried `var d = moment({day: 0, month: 0, year: 0, hour: 10, minute: 30})` but calling `d.day()` returns 6.

By the way, if that's possible, is there an easier way to do this without passing the date components as showed above?

Comment: Do you want to extract out only hour and minute part of some date ?

Comment: I know how to extract only hour and minute, but I also would like that the date object had no date part (day, month, and year), like it was a truly 'Time' object, if you will.

Comment: The Moment library works off of the Epoch, so when you pass in those values, you're literally saying you want day 0, month 0 (which is january) and year 0. What are you hoping to achieve by passing in static values fir hour and minute? 

Using `moment()` will return the current date time and from there you can format the returned value using the options found in the formatting docs to output only hour and minute: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: I'm going to have two date objects and I will need to get the difference between them and also add this difference with the difference between others two date objects. I'm afraid that if the date objects have date information (day, month, year) these manipulations won't work properly. I only need time information (hour and minute). Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. When talking about dates, there no such thing day 0.

But, if you only care about time difference you could use moment.duration, or diff.

```
var dur = moment.duration({ minute: 30 }).add(moment.duration({ minute: 40 }));
console.log(dur.minutes());
console.log(dur.hours());
```

Outputs

```
10
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the information that there's no such thing as day 0.